# Number Theory: $x^2+y^2=a^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a coprime triple $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2=a^2, x^2+z^2=b^2, y^2+z^2=c^2$, where $a,b,c$ are integers

P.S. such solution doesn't exist for $a,b,c<1000$, as the computer says

P.P.S. the statement above is WRONG

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What's its background?Is it part of a bigger problem or setup...?

Comment: @DonAntonio not sure...saw it online at another site

Comment: chapter 19 in Volume 2 of Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers

Comment: @WillJagy thanks that's some useful reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called Euler brick,the smallest one is $x=44,y=117,z=240$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick

Comment: Seems his computer program is not quite what it should be then.

Comment: so, my program went wrong again then XD. thx a lot

Answer (score -1):

x = 720
y = 132
z = 85
a = 732
b = 725
c = 157

Comment: It would help if you could add details on how you came to this answer. Regards